# Parish vs church

Tags: difference

Is my distinctions of "parish" and "church" correct? According to the Google definition, a parish is "a small administrative district typically having its own church and a priest or pastor." To me, it feels like a parish is the land itself, and the church is the building. Am I right, or is there more to it? (I'm actually specifically referring to the usage in *The Crucible*, but answers discussing modern usage are also appreciated.)

Comment: *"a parish is the land itself"* - a parish is a *geographic area* or a *locality*, but one determined by ecclesiastical rather than secular authorities. I wouldn't say it refers to "the land itself", because it can be used in the capacity of referring to the church congregation or the people of the locality collectively. The same is true of "the church" - it can mean the building, but also the ecclesiastical administration collectively, or the congregation collectively. The exact sense would depend on context and implication.

Comment: I agree with Steve as far as *a parish is the land itself" - a parish is a geographic area or a locality, but one determined by ecclesiastical rather than secular authorities.* that is exactly what it is - the church was part of the parish. However, by extension (the technical term is "synecdoche") such examples as *"The parish spoke with one voice." = everyone in the parish agreed*, i.e. the "parish" did not speak. And "The parish is valued at £300" included all the buildings.

Comment: @Steve Certainly in the UK and, I believe, in Jamaica, and possibly other former British colonies, a Parish can be the lowest level of local authority in rural areas. These parishes are referred to as Civil Parishes and have no official connection with any place of worship. In the UK there is usually more than one parish covering a given place, the Civil Parish (where one exists) which is a legal entity and can levy taxes, the Anglican parish, a Roman Catholic parish and sometimes a Greek or Russian Orthodox parish. There may be others as well but I'm not sure.

Comment: It depends on the church, and what their chosen terminology is.

Comment: This entire discussion is shamelessly parochial. Not sure about the synecdoche, though, @Greybeard; I'm thinking of where H.D.F. Kitto interprets a line from Sophocles, "the whole *polis* heard," as evidence that that term at least can refer literally to the people as opposed to the land-base or town. *Parish* as the people thereof can easily be likewise literal, even though imagined lines on the land may define which parish which people are of.

Comment: As @BoldBen says. In England the Parish Council is a local government body, while the Parochial Church Council is the committee which administers the local Anglican church. Of course, civil parishes originated  with ecclesiastical parishes.

Comment: @BrianDonovan I think that *"the whole polis heard,"* as evidence that that term at least can refer literally to the people" is a little thin, Greek and relatively modern and can, given context, include animals. But nevertheless, I did say "by extension" and when a thing is extended it reaches and includes another point. Whether that is "literal" is then a matter of interpretation. In, for example "We need more boots on the ground", there is little doubt that there will literally be boots.

Comment: It should be noted that Louisiana uses the term "parish" to refer to what would be called a "county" in most other states.

Comment: @HotLicks That's what I understand to be the situation in Jamaica as well. I wonder if the French split the parts of the territory that were settled by Europeans into parishes before the Louisiana Purchase.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments indicate, "parish" means a lot of different things these days, such that I doubt anyone could answer it exhaustively.

However, at its most basic level, a "parish" refers to the geographical area served by a church *or* the group of people who attend that church (individually: parishioners).

The word originates from Roman Catholic usage, which divided up all of Christendom into dioceses (headed by bishops in a cathedral) and then divided those dioceses into parishes (headed by priests in a church).  Every person in Europe lived in *some* parish and was expected to attend and support its church, and the churches forwarded any leftover money to their diocese.  If a parish outgrew its church, the diocese would split off part of the parish and build it a new church, and the people living in that area would be ordered to attend and support their new church instead.

The separation of church and state broke that system to varying degrees in various places, depending on how separated they were in practice, and the result is that the term "parish" now means quite different things depending on exactly where the word is used.  It can range from being a historical artifact to a secular government division to a religious entity with tax power, or possibly other things even weirder.  There's no single answer.